# "Оба" и "обе": как правильно употреблять?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, числительные, морфемный-разбор, русская-графика

Как верно употреблять числительные "оба" и "обе" применительно к м. р. + ж. р.? Например: "Мы *оба* идём к тебе (муж.+жен.)".

Answer (score 2):

**Мы оба идём к тебе**.

"Обе", "обеих" пишется только по отношению к женскому роду. По отношению к мужскому, среднему, общему родам, а также *к сочетанию женского рода и другого* пишется "оба", "обоих".